# Surjective map $H \to A \ast_C B$ means $H$ is an amalgamated free product

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Suppose we have a free product with amalgamation $G = A \ast_C B$ with $A \neq C$ and $B \neq C$.

I want to show that if we have a surjective homomorphism $f : H \to G$, where $H$ is some group (no conditions on it), then $H = A' \ast_{C'} B'$ with $A' \neq C' \neq B'$.

My ideas so far:

The map is surjective so $\frac{H}{\ker f} \cong G$. If your quotient is an amalgamated free product, are you also one? Probably not.

Maybe from a geometric point of view: $G$ acts on a tree $T$ with fundamental domain $e = [P,Q]$ (a single edge with two vertices), with $\text{stab}(P) = A$, $\text{stab}(Q) = B$ and $\text{stab}(e) = C$. $H$ acts on this tree too, via $f$. I think maybe the fundamental domain $T/H$ is also just one edge so $H$ is an amalgamated free product. But I can't really see why this is true.

Comment: To be a nontrivial amalgam meant to have an inversion-free action on an unbounded tree, with fundamental domain a segment. So it is clearly inherited from $G$ to any group $H$ with a surjective homomorphism onto $G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map $f\colon H \to G$ gives an action of $H$ on a tree with identical quotient but different stabilizer information. In this case, write $K = \ker f$. Then $\operatorname{stab}(P) = f^{-1}(A)$, $\operatorname{stab}(Q) = f^{-1}(B)$, and $\operatorname{stab}(e) = f^{-1}(C)$. One way to see this is that under this action, the stabilizer in $H$ with this action should be the full preimage of the stabilizer in $G$, which is exactly what we've written.

Comment: Yes, I see this now. Given this, I also see why we need surjectivity to show that $A \neq C$ implies $f^{-1}(A) \neq f^{-1}(C)$, so we get a genuine splitting of the group $H$. But just to make sure, you haven't yet used surjectivity in your answer, right?

Comment: Yes, I suppose this argument shows that any homomorphism into an amalgamated free product yields a (possibly trivial) splitting. To argue that it is a genuine splitting, I just need to show that the image of $f$ contains an element in $A\setminus C$ and an element in $B\setminus C$. A fortiori this is true by surjectivity, but I think this weaker condition should be enough in general.